# Unresolved reference: ActivityCompat in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am implementing OCR results in android using kotlin language by this [tutorial](https://medium.com/teachmind/detect-text-from-image-in-android-with-google-mobile-vision-api-112a527e556d)

I am unable to solve this `ActivityCompat error`

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat
```

My Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ocrofflinesample"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
   // implementation 'androidx.support:appcompat-v7:'

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.4"

    //  Logger
    implementation 'com.orhanobut:logger:2.1.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}

How to resolve this `ActivityCompat error`?
```

Comment: post your dependencies

Comment: @FaridForootan : I added the dependencies in my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use Androidx dependency. Change the `android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat` to `androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat`

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) out for pre-Androidx to Androidx dependencies mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You might have either used `AndroidX` while creating project, or you have used `AndroidX` dependencies in non - androidX artifact.

Either you need to migrate it to androidX as suggested above.

> Also, if you have used `app:layout_scrollFlags` in layouts, you
>   might wanna check out the scroll constants after refactor because
>   recently when I refactored, I didn't get any build error but when the
>   activity with `scrollFlags` loaded, it crashed and upon finding
>   out, it was a refactor issue due to that it was unable to change
>   constant names as per AndroidX.